# How would you go about transforming an object of m vertices through a sequence of n transformations?

Tags: transformation, linear-algebra

In 3D space, I understand - in concept at least - how to use a matrix transformation to move a point.

However, if I have a shape - let's say a cube - with a number of points (vertexes), do I need to run each point through the matrix transformations or is there a faster way to do them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

For a single vertex, you have

`b=Aa`

where `a=(x,y,z)` is the column of the coordinates of the point, and `b` contains the coordinates of the transformed point. `A` is your `3x3` transformation matrix.

if you use a programming language with fast matrix multiplication, you can write

`XP=A X`

where each columns of `X` contains the coordinates `(x,y,z)` of each vertex of your cube and the columns of `XP` contain the transformed coordinates of each vertex.

This requires you to stack up in the matrix `X` your vertices, but is usually faster then looping over each vertex.

edit:

If you have more than one transformation to apply in series one after the other, for example for 3 of them, pick `A=A3 A2 A1` with `A1` the first you want to apply, `A2` the second and `A3` the third.